# Grey box rendering StandaloneSearchBox of react-google-maps

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-maps, google-api

I have the next error: [grey box in form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hq4uQ.jpg)

when I'm rendering StandaloneSearchBox import from react-google-maps, sometimes appear or disappear that grey box over the text input

this is my code:

```
render() {
new window.google.maps.places.SearchBox('HOL');
return (
  <div className="g-autocomplete">
    <StandaloneSearchBox
    
      onPlacesChanged={this.onPlacesChanged}
      ref={searchBox => { this.searchBox = searchBox; }}
      >
      <input
        className={this.props.className ? this.props.className : ''}
        type="text"
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder ? this.props.placeholder : ''}
        style={this.state.defaultStyle}
      />
      
    </StandaloneSearchBox>
    
  </div>



);
```

}

Comment: I would suggest looking at the various input pseudoclasses on :hover, :input, :focus, it could be the custom styling is not overwriting the existing styles from the component.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Comment: Make sure to use the correct API key and include [places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library) in your code.